# Request myself in Nodejs deployed on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, axios

I have a Node Express App deployed on Heroku. The main page needs around 50 HTTP Requests to external services to display the data. The requests take so long, so Im using cache.

Now Im tring to request the webpage periodically to myself in order to force Node to continue refreshing and caching the data. This way the user wont have to wait 1 minutes to see the page.

Following code works perfectly on local. But at production enviroment (Heroku) I get `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED`

```
setInterval(function() {
  var url = "http://127.0.0.1:" + (process.env.PORT || 3000);
  try {
    http.get(url, {})
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error refreshing data')
    console.error(err)
  }
}, 1 * 60 * 1000)
```

I have tried:

- `http://127.0.0.1:" + (process.env.PORT || 3000)`
- `https://127.0.0.1:" + (process.env.PORT || 3000)`
- `0.0.0.0`

Any way to find the correct ip/host and port?

**UPDATE**

Name of the host (`https://nameofapp.herokuapp.com/`) actually works. But is there any way to call myself without knowing the host?

Comment: "Now Im tring to request the webpage to myself in order to force Node to continue refreshing and caching the data." I found this unclear. How does this help your user complete their 50 HTTP requests? Or why are you doing this?

Comment: All the 50 api calls to external services take around 1 minute (even more) and are done in the server. I need Node to refresh that data periodically. Calling myself makes the cached data refresh (if its expired). Question updated. I think it wasn't enough clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [request-myself](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-myself)

Try this code:

```
const requestMyself = require('request-myself');
const option = {
    hostname: process.env.BASE_URL,
    timeout: process.env.TIME_IDLING
};

app.use(requestMyself(option, (error, res) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error('RequestMyself error:', error);
    } else {
        console.info('RequestMyself statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    }
}));
```

set your environment variable `BASE_URL` is your app's url, `TIME_IDLING` is timeout to request (or you can change when define `option`)

If you has some problem, you feel free to create an issue

Check [dyno-metadata](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-metadata), to auto generate `HEROKU_APP_NAME` and some `env` (`process.env.HEROKU_APP_NAME`), use it to get your host

Comment: Thanks for your response! but this is not different from what im doing. Actually I want to call myself without knowing the host.

Comment: If that, please check document : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-metadata